# bsearch not able to search element that is smaller to its previous element

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, data-structures, bsearch

I've been working in my activity that involves searching an array and i'm currently using bsearch for that matter. The problem is that whenever that element is smaller to its previous element, the bsearch could not search it. And what's more is that this problems starts to occur when the element I am searching is in an index that is greater than or equal to 3.
I'm coding in C btw. Please I desperately need your help guys and it would be highly appreciated thanks.
Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

typedef struct{
  int elements[MAX];
  int count;
}SET;

int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b) {
  return (*(int*)a > *(int*)b) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b);
}

void print(SET *s1, SET *s2){
  int key = 2;
  int *p;
  p = bsearch(&key,&s1->elements,s1->count,sizeof(int),cmpfunc);
  printf("%p",p,sizeof(s1->elements));

  return;
}

int main () {
  SET s1 = {{1,5,4,2,6,3},6};
  SET s2 = {{1,29,3,5},4};

  print(&s1,&s2);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `bsearch` works only with sorted data, you need to insert them ordered or call `qsort` before using `bsearch`

Comment: From  [`man 3 bsearch`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch): *The contents of the array should be in ascending sorted order according to the comparison function referenced by compar.*

Comment: @ava.begginer Why are there more arguments in this call  printf("%p",p,sizeof(s1->elements)); than it is required?

Comment: @ava.begginer If an array is not ordered use the linear search in a loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow nope, I just printed it for debugging purposes hehehe, my bad

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind support and response. I just never realized it that I first need to sort it in ascending order. I was so confused already with a ton of coding projects. Thank you again everyone for your help

Comment: But isn't it quite inefficient to use bsearch in tandem with qsort this way? Than just running a loop with if to find the item?
Thank you for the reply

Comment: If you only do a single search - then no, not efficient. But if you perform many searches, it worth to first sort the array.